# Developing providers for OpenSSL 3

Tags: c, ssh, openssl, cryptography

I'm in the process of updating an application (hpn-ssh) that uses a modified AES-CTR cipher (it's threaded for additional performance - we didn't change the underlying cipher itself). Under OpenSSL 1.x we could simply redirect the calls using _meth_new and _meth_set. OpenSSL 3 no longer support this method and directs people to use the provider interface. Which is great but the documentation is, at times, frustrating. For example, does the provider need to be built as a library which is then loaded into OpenSSL or can it be self contained with in the application itself? Does a cipher need to define parameters or are they optional? And so on. I've been going through the source code to answer some of these questions but it's slow going.

I was wondering if anyone knew of any good resources - examples, discussions, tutorials, etc. that can help answer some of these questions or at least give me a toehold into things?

Answer (score 2):

There's a "toy" provider implementation of a cipher here:

https://github.com/provider-corner/vigenere

> does the provider need to be built as a library which is then loaded into OpenSSL or can it be self contained with in the application itself

It can be self contained within the application. Use the function `OSSL_PROVIDER_add_builtin` to do this:

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/OSSL_PROVIDER_add_builtin.html

Comment: Thank you. I'm actually talking with the guy that developed that now. I was aware of the add_builtin() function but it didn't seem to explicitly say "use this when you roll it into your application". I have been using it on the assumption that it does that so it's good to get confirmation.